# Change only default's user's signature via API in Gmail

Tags: api, google-email-settings-api

I have added another email address I own to my gmail account. I have a signature for the default account and another one for the secondary.

Now, what I want to do is to change via API the signature of the default account. If I use email setting API as it is written in the documentation:

```
client = gdata.apps.emailsettings.client.EmailSettingsClient(domain='yourdomain')
client.ClientLogin(email='adminUsername@yourdomain', password='adminPassword', source='your-apps')
client.UpdateSignature(username='liz', signature='')
```

it changes both signatures, the one of the default account and the one of the secondary account.

Is there any way of changing only the default's account's signature via API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to do this. The [Email Settings API signature update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#updating_a_signature) method will update all signatures for the given user.